# WCF continues to use TLS 1.0 and RSA even when set to Tls12

Tags: .net, wcf, security, ssl

I have a Windows service that runs a WCF `WebServiceHost` targeted at .NET 4.6.1 running on Windows Server 2008r2.  I've asked it to use TLS 1.2:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
m_host = new WebServiceHost(m_scriptingServer, new Uri("https://localhost:666"));
WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
ServiceEndpoint ep = m_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IScriptingServer), binding, "");
m_host.open();
```

but when I use Chrome 49 to connect to the service I still get the connection warning:

> Your connection to example.com:666 is encrypted using an obsolete cipher suite.
> The connection uses TLS 1.0.
>
> The connection is encrypted using AES_128_CBC, with HMAC-SHA1 for message authentication and RSA as the key exchange mechanism.

Why doesn't it use TLS1.2?  How can I get rid of this warning?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I needed to add

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server\DisabledByDefault = 0` (DWORD)

to the registry (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245030).  The WebServiceHost would then negotiate TLS 1.2 with Chrome.

I then added

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server\Enabled = 0` (DWORD)

to block TLS 1.0... which promptly broke Remote Desktop and locked me out of the machine.  If you're going to do that look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3080079 beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a magic registry key you need to set. Via 64 bit powershell:

```
# set strong cryptography on 64 bit .Net Framework (version 4 and above)
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord


# set strong cryptography on 32 bit .Net Framework (version 4 and above)
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord
```

http://johnlouros.com/blog/enabling-strong-cryptography-for-all-dot-net-applications

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me.  Adding those values didn't change the behavior on Server 2008r2 before or after I added the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server\DisabledByDefault = 0` value.